# jQuery: check if column contains certain value

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, each

I have a standard table that contains various values. The same value may appear in different TDs but not within the same column.

**Example:**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>text1</td>
        <td>text2</td>
        <td>text3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text4</td>
        <td>text5</td>
        <td>text6</td>
    </tr>
    <!--more TRs...-->
</table>
```

Is there a way I can use jQuery to check whether a certain column contains a certain value and return 1 if yes or 0 if no ?

**Example:** 
When applying this to the second column above and check for "`text2`" it should return 1; if I check for "`text5`" it should return 1 as well; if I check for "`text6`" it should return 0 as not existing in this column.

**I was thinking of starting something like:**

```
$('#myTable td:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
    //...
});
```

Thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
$.fn.colCheck = function(col, text) {
    var c = Array.isArray(col) ? col : [col],
        t = this,
        a = [];

    $.each(c, function(_, v){
        a.push(
            t.find('tr td').filter(function() {
                return $(this).index() === (v-1) && $.trim($(this).text()) === text;
            }).length
        );
    });
    return a.length === 1 ? a[0] : a;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RTrZh/1/)

to be used like

```
$('#myTable').colCheck([1,2,3], 'text5'); // pass array, return array [0,1,0]
$('#myTable').colCheck(2, 'text2'); // 1
```

would return the number of occurences of that text in the given column.

Comment: This is perfect - thanks a lot for the quick reply !

Comment: One more question on this: Could I also apply this to several columns at the same time ? Like in the above example, to check columns 1, 2 and 3 separately and then return an array like [0, 1, 0] ?

Comment: @user2571510 - Nope, but I can change it to accept arrays -> **http://jsfiddle.net/RTrZh/1/**

Comment: Awesome. Yes, that's perfect. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>text1</td>
        <td class="check">text2</td>
        <td>text3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>text4</td>
        <td class="check">text5</td>
        <td>text6</td>
    </tr>
    //more TRs...
</table>
```

and jquery:

```
function check()

{

var flag = 0;
$('#myTable td.check').each(function(){


if($(this).html() == '')
{
flag = 0;
return flag;
}

else
{
flag = 1;
}


})
return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function mycheck(what) {
        var result = 0;
        $( "#myTable td" ).each(function( index ) {
            var myval = $( this ).text();
            if ((index - 1) % 3 == 0 ) {
                if (myval == what) {
                    result = 1; return result; 
                }                   
            }               
        });
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: this is wrote for specific column from your exaple (second column)