# jQuery: change function to return text instead of length

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, filter, each

I got the below function from this forum which checks if a column contains a certain value and returns 1 if yes or 0 if not. Source: [jQuery: check if column contains certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028594/jquery-check-if-column-contains-certain-value).
This works great so far.

Is there a way I can change this to return the actual TD text in case a column contains the search value (where it currently returns 1) ?
So in the end an example output would look like `[0, TDtext, 0]` instead of `[0, 1, 0]` ?

I guess I can replace }).length by }).text() in this case but wasn't sure how to adjust the rest.

```
$.fn.colCheck = function(col) {
    var c = Array.isArray(col) ? col : [col],
        t = this,
        a = [];

    $.each(c, function(_, v){
        a.push(
            t.find('tr td.myClass').filter(function() {
                return $(this).index() === (v-1);
            }).length ? text : 0
        );
    });
    return a.length === 1 ? a[0] : a;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it to

```
$.each(c, function(_, v){
    a.push(
        t.find('tr td').filter(function() {
            return $(this).index() === (v-1) && $.trim($(this).text()) === text;
        }).length ? text : 0
    );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RTrZh/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I posted it separately as I wasn't sure I can reactive the other post.

Comment: That's ok, it's related, but still different as it asks for a different result.

Comment: Ok, I had to modify this a little as it turned out I can't use it this way. So instead of referring to a search term I can now refer to a class. I tried to change the function but the "? text : 0" does not return anything - I updated the revised function above. Sorry for that !

Comment: If you're not passing text to search for, the entire premise of the function changes, and I'm not sure what you're supposed to search for anymore or how the class is relevant other than for filtering? Are you trying to get the text from the class or something ?

Comment: Yes, the class will be applied to all TDs that contain the search term. So the intention is the same I just need to search by the class instead of by the search term. I updated my post above.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain better: Your initial function worked great and returned 0 if a column did not contain the search term and 1 if it did. I had to change this as I have to refer to a class instead of a search term + I would need the TDs text instead of returning 1. So if a column contains a TD with "myClass" then it should return this TDs text, otherwise it should return 0 ("myClass" can only appear max. once within a column). Does that help ?

Comment: Just to add: your updated function works great too (I must have missed something there before) so this is just about replacing the search term reference by a class reference, everything else looks perfect.

Comment: This is it - thank so much for that ! I had tried as well but couldnt figure out how to adjust the text part. Thanks again - I really appreciate it.